# Angularjs when typing in input is paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using jQuery to figure out when an input has started typing and then paused.

```
var timeoutId;
$('#container').on('input propertychange change', 'form', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log("paused");
    }, 3000);
});
```

I'm trying to find an appropriate Angularjs solution to accomplish this task.

I'm thinking I need to use `ng-change` or something similar to my input areas. I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the answer. You would do this where `3000` is the amount of milliseconds you want to wait.

```
<input ng-change="functionToRun()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 3000}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: @bryan has the correct answer!

You can use the ng-change directive on your inputs and the $timeout service to handle your pause event.

Working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y6NtjabxeGaQpOIif1U3?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="inputExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('inputExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$timeout', '$scope', function($timeout, $scope) {
        $scope.checkPause = function() {
          $timeout.cancel($scope.pause);
          $scope.pause = $timeout(function() {
            alert("pause");
          }, 1000);
        };
      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="myForm">
      <label>
        User name:
        <input ng-change="checkPause()" type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required>
      </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```